Jmeter performance Report
I'm using jmeter and I am testing my API. So in that API I have to test for 3 different thread groups (1 thread,100 and 1000 threads) and get as sum of all threads as a report in html file.
But I need individual sections for every thread group for their performance report in one html file.

I can think of the following options:

There is threadName column in the .jtl results file, you can distinguish results coming from different Thread Groups and split the file into 3 parts. Then either generate 3 different HTML Reporting Dashboards or create the HTML page with the data you want from these CSV files
Add 3 listeners like Simple Data Writer to write results into different .jtl files
Use Backend Listener to send results to InfluxDB and then come up with JMeter Grafana dashboard to display the metrics you want in the way you want

